# WearableListenerService only wakes up when I open my app

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have successfully implemented communication between my phone and watch app through WearableListenerServices in both modules. This works perfectly for the most part, however, if i don't use the phone app in a while the watch app stops communicating. This suggests the WearableListenerService is not "woken" up as expected. To fix this, I have to open the phone app and for the next while the watch app communicates perfectly again.

Is there a way I can guarantee that it will be "woken" up? Or am I missing something?

Phone manifest:

```
<service android:name=".app.util.ListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:scheme="wear" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Wear app:

```
<service android:name=".util.ListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:scheme="wear" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

If you need more on the specific implementation of the listeners I'm happy to provide it, but it doesn't seem relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever got this working? Same issue here

Comment: @user2161301 unfortunately not sorry, I've also moved away from Android dev so  I can't point you in any direction either.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Got it working like 80% of the times now by updating GMS or whatever the API need to work but 80% still is really bad, let's see what I can find

Answer (score 0):

We all knew that the [BIND_LISTENER for wearable app is already deprecated](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/deprecation-of-bindlistener.html) and it is replaced by a fine-grained intent filter. So make sure that you use a correct filters for your app. You can know the meaning and purpose of individual filters [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService).

Try to check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html) for Building Apps for Wearables, it shows you how to use the `WearableListenerService` for your app. It also provide some sample code that you can verify if you properly implemented this code in your application.